# Attempting AS ExternalInterface call from JavaScript gives Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

> I'm attempting to get a basic example of an `ExternalInterface` call working. The aim: send a string to a flash object and have it return it, which I can then `console.log`.

I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when trying to call the method on my flash object.

I am using `allowScriptAccess` in both the `object` and `embed` tags, and I'm checking there aren't any race conditions with both a `setTimeout()` and using `$(window).on("load")` instead of `$(document).ready();` - yet I still get the above error.

I have placed the following actionscript in the first keyframe of my flash animation:

```
import flash.external.*;
import flash.system.*;

// Params: First the function to call in JS, second the function run within AS
ExternalInterface.addCallback("test", sayHerro);

function sayHerro():String {
    return "HERRO OMFG";
}
```

So I have defined a function, `sayHerro()`, that takes no parameters and returns a `String`. This should be executed when my JavaScript calls `test` on the swf object.

Here is the HTML holding the element in the body:

```
<object height="640" id="myFlashMovie"> // note the id is myFlashMovie
    <param value="inbanner-mpu.swf" name="movie" />
    <param value="true" name="swLiveConnect" /> // Apparently I need this...
    <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess" /> // and also this...

    // Note the src is the same as above (the animation does display), the name is the same, and this also has the allowscriptaccess tag
    <embed height="640" src="inbanner-mpu.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="myFlashMovie"></embed> 
</object>
```

And finally here is my JavaScript which waits half a second before executing and attempting to call `test()` on the swf object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var swf = document.getElementById("myFlashMovie");
            console.log(swf);
            swf.test();
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Why am I getting the `TypeError`? I must be doing something really daft but I just can't figure out where my issue is.

In case of relevance:

- Browser: Chrome (latest stable)
- Flash: CS6

Comment: Please notice that "AllowScriptAccess" takes three upper cases letter, in the param name and in the embed. I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: I think that your problem is caused by the fact, that while document is already loaded, swf is not. Can you to change timeout from 500ms to let's say 10000ms? Just to find out if the idea is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I was mixing up my actionscript versions, so I've left what I've figured out in the hopes that future users may find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, this was a *really* silly thing - but it's pretty important so I'll leave this here for future viewers. I knew I was doing something daft.

*ActionScript 2 and ActionScript 3 have different parameter requirements* for `ExternalInterface::addCallback()` - this can really mess things up for you!

### ActionScript 2

[Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001037.html)

```
public static addCallback(methodName: String, instance: Object, method: function)
```

**methodName** - a string that the JavaScript will call 
**instance** - the object to which `this` resolves in the method. I set it to null. 
**method** - the method you want called in your actionscript

You'll note that this method returns a **boolean**.

### ActionScript 3

[Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

```
public static addCallback(functionName: String, closure: Function)
```

**methodName** - a string that the JavaScript will call 
**closure** - the method you want called in your actionscript

You'll note that this method returns **void**.

---

I did spend half a day trying to figure this out, so hopefully the above is useful. *Check what version of actionscript you are working with first*. Then use the above to figure out whether you need two parameters or three.